# Why I cannot upload an image to a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a big trouble when trying to upload an image (using `PHP`) to a database (`phpMyAdmin`). Everything seems fine to me even debugging (using `eclipse`).
When I run my code the image is uploaded, the SQL-query is launched and the image is moved from the tmp-folder. But nothing in my database. Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['upload']) && $_FILES['upload']['size'] > 0) {
    $file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'];

    if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        $img->uploadImg($size, $type, $name, $data);
    }
    $older = getcwd () . '/image/'. basename($name);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $folder);
}
```

And:

```
  public function uploadImg($size, $mimetype, $filename, $code) {
            try {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO img_table(fileName, size, mimetype, code) VALUES ($filename, $size, $mimetype, $code)";
                $this->db->exec($sql);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $sql.' '.$e->getMessage();
            }
}
```

Any idea or hint to tell me where I am doing wrong. i am open to any suggestions.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: Add error reporting to your php code by appending  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`  at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: U need to use quotes for string values

Comment: "INSERT INTO img_table(fileName, size, mimetype, code) VALUES ('$filename', '$size', '$mimetype', '$code')";

Comment: You also need to escape the binary image data. But it would be best if you used a prepared query.

Comment: `@devpro`  Same problem using quotes for string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't quote the string values in the query. And since the image is binary, you also need to escape it.

But the way to avoid all these issues is to use a prepared statement.

```
public function uploadImg($size, $mimetype, $filename, $code) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO img_table(fileName, size, mimetype, code) VALUES (:filename, :size, :mimetype, :code)"
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':filename' => $filename,
            ':size' => $size,
            ':mimetype' => $mimetype,
            ':code' => $code);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql.' '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Barmar` It dosen't work. What do you mean with `I have to escape the image?`

Comment: `$code` contains binary data, not plain text. You can't just put that directly into a SQL query string.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Why are you putting the image data into the DB, instead of just using the file?

Comment: No error message. how to use a file? how to do that? I can try this way.

Comment: `@Barmar` IT WORKS now. I forgot to refresh the DB. Very big thanks for your help. Very appreciate it.

Comment: You're already using the file with `move_uploaded_file`. So all you need to do is read from that file when you want to send the image.

Comment: OK. An idea is more powerful. Thanks again.